# Background processing for long running JS operation in Trigger.io? - forge.tabs module?

Tags: javascript, trigger.io

In my Trigger.IO app I'm scanning through all contacts in the device phonebook. This takes a long time (+30s), and I want to provide the best expeirence for my users by allowing them to continue to use other features of the app while the scanning takes place. Ideally the scanning would take place without any interruption to the user.

Is there a way to do this in Trigger.IO? I wondered if the forge.tabs module could be used in someway -  does a script running in the tab share the same thread as the main webview? If I close the tab can I continue to run a script in it or is it destroyed?

Suggestions of how I can approach this problem would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the code snippet you're currently using to interact with the contacts, and details of the device / emulator you're testing with?

Comment: If your app is still active (not paused/closed), you can easily defer the contact lookup via a setTimeout call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calls won't block JS execution - you can start the scanning and still respond to user input: maybe showing a spinner somewhere if they're unable to proceed further at this point.

In your case, I *think* you're talking about lots of small requests, rather than a long one. If you're worried about them impacting the responsiveness of the UI, you could experiment with running the next API interaction in a setTimeout with a small delay, which will let any other pending JS tasks start running.

Comment: Yes that is exactly it James - I'm doing one `forge.contact.selectAll()` to get all the IDs, and then for each ID doing a `forge.contact.selectById()`. I haven't got round to trying `setTimeout` on this yet but will report back when I do. By the way, being able to pass a list of fields I want to `forge.contact.selectById()` would be useful. Currently I'm only interested in one: emails.